# Getting AutoQuery pagination to work with left join

Tags: servicestack

In my AutoQuery request I have a left join specified so I can query on properties in the joined table.

```
public class ProductSearchRequest : QueryDb<Book>
    , ILeftJoin<Book, BookAuthor>, ILeftJoin<BookAuthor, Author>
{}
```

If I use standard way of autoquery like so:

```
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request);
var results = AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
```

And 100 are being requested, then often less than 100 will be retuned as the `Take()` is based on results with a left join.

To remedy this I am doing this instead:

```
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request);
q.OrderByExpression = null //throws error if orderby exists
var total = Db.Scalar<int>(q.Select(x => Sql.CountDistinct(x.Id))); //returns 0

var q1 = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request).GroupBy(x => x);

var results = Db.Select<Book>(q1);

return new QueryResponse<Book>
{
    Offset = q1.Offset.GetValueOrDefault(0),
    Total = total
    Results = results
};
```

The group by appears to return correct number of results so paging works but the `Total` returns 0.

I also tried:

```
var total2 = (int)Db.Count(q1);
```

But even though `q1` has a `GroupBy()` it returns the number of results including the left join and not the actual query

How can I get the true total of the query?

(Getting some official docs on how to do paging and totals with autoquery & left join would be very helpful as right now it's a bit confusing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue stems from trying to return a different total then the actual query AutoQuery executes. If you have multiple left joins, the total is the total results of the query it executes not the number of rows in your source table.

So you're not looking for the "True total", rather you're looking to execute a different query to get a different total than the query that's executed, but still deriving from the original query as its basis. First consider using normal INNER JOINS (`IJoin<>`) instead of LEFT JOINS so it only returns results for related rows in joined tables which the total will reflect accordingly.

Your total query that returns `0` is likely returning no results, so I'd look at looking at the query in an SQL Profiler so you can see the query that's executed. You can also enable logging of OrmLite queries with **Debug** logging enabled and in your AppHost:

```
OrmLiteUtils.PrintSql();
```

Also note that `GroupBy()` of the entire table is unusual, you would normally group by a single or multiple explicit selected columns, e.g:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
```

Comment: If I use an inner join then I lose half the data set because not every left table has an entry in right table.  The group by throws an error unless i list every property and the table has lots of properties.  If I group by x then it seems to list all properties out for me.  The groupby returns the right number of results but the count statement doesn't count it properly as it returns multiple rows because of groupby.  I need to have the group by statement as a sub query in order to get correct count but cant see in docs how to do this.  Its very frustrating

Comment: @Guerrilla Do you know what the behavior of including the aggregate COUNT(...) with a GROUP BY is? It's likely not what you want/think. If you just want the number of rows of a query you may want to call `db.RowCount(q)` instead otherwise I'd start with the actual SQL Query you want actually to execute first, then look how you can query it in OrmLite - the total will be the aggregate of all `COUNT(...)` columns, so make sure that's returning the total you want.

Comment: `(int)Db.RowCount(q1.ClearLimits())` seems to work for the counts thank you.  I think you are right about the groupby, I will need to list out every property manually

Comment: @Guerrilla Paginating queries with left joins require a different strategy, e.g. by maintaining a reference and querying the [last key the query was ordered by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876989/85785) or doing the [pagination within a sub query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283264/85785) before the left joins.

Comment: The problem with doing a subselect for the page and then joining the tables to the subselect is that you can then only query the one page and not the entire dataset by the joined tables columns.  The `db.RowCount()` has made totals work.  I will investigate why I am unable to just group by ID.  Thank you for your help.  It's working now but I am unsure if I have done it right.  I think some official docs of pagination with autoquery joins would be helpful as its a common task and not mentioned in docs.